# pagination on array laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and I try to use pagination for my products

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => Product {#770 ▶}
  1 => Product {#766 ▶}
  2 => Product {#814 ▶}
  3 => Product {#846 ▶}
]
```

And I get these from a method like this

```
$this->getAllCategoriesProducts(31)
```

31 is ID of category

and this is my method :

```
  public function getAllCategoriesProducts($cat_id){
      $allProducts = [];
      foreach(ProductCategory::find($cat_id)->children()->get() as $subCategory){
        if($subCategory->children()->exists()){
          foreach($subCategory->children()->get() as $subSubCategory){
            foreach($subSubCategory->products()->get() as $product){
            $allProducts[] = $product;
            }
          }
          if($subSubCategory->children()->exists()){
            foreach($subSubCategory->children()->get() as $subSubSubCategory){
              foreach($subSubSubCategory->products()->get() as $product){
              $allProducts[] = $product;
              }
              if($subSubSubCategory->children()->exists()){
                foreach($subSubSubCategory->children()->get() as $subSubSubSubCategory){
                  foreach($subSubSubSubCategory->products()->get() as $product){
                  $allProducts[] = $product;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return $allProducts;
    }
```

but when I use

```
$this->getAllCategoriesProducts($categroyId)->paginate(8)
```

it gives me this error

> Call to a member function paginate() on array

Comment: Laravel's paginator is integrated with the query builder and Eloquent ORM.
Check the document https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#introduction

Comment: Pagination is less valuable if you still get the entire result set per page. If you provide a better description of what data you want from which tables we can help you better.

Comment: @online Thomas I have multi level category so with above method I get all related categories products and I want to paginate them just this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add paginator manually like this.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

$products = $this->getAllCategoriesProducts(31);
$total = count($products);
$perPage = 5; // How many items do you want to display.
$currentPage = 1; // The index page.
$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($products, $total, $perPage, $currentPage);
```